# Add a Label inside the border of an HBox or a VBox

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to add a Label - i.e. some text inside the border of a JavaFX HBox. The text should sit in the top left corner of the HBox and be inside the visible border area. I used to be able to do this in Swing, but I haven't figured out how to do it in JavaFX.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860960/groupbox-titledborder-in-javafx-2)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I'll delete post in a minute!