# JavaFX: ClassNotFoundException for imported class in FXML

Tags: javafx, textfield, fxml, titled-border

I'm trying to create a textfield with a title embedded in the field border like:

[image]

Following the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14874195/4731712) I've created a .java file called `TitledBorder.java` within my `src>main>java` directory. My FXML is in the `src>main>resources` directory and I've added:

`<?import TitledBorder?>` at the top and it shows no error like:
[image]

I then added this code to the FXML

```
<HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <children>
      <TitledBorder title="Email" >
        <TextField fx:id="emailField" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="143.0" />
      </TitledBorder>
    </children>
</HBox>
```

and it shows no error either. I then launch my main method which is in a class also in src>main>java but it gets an error in the .fxml saying `javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/ME/Documents/Automation/target/classes/demofxml.fxml`

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2899)
```

I'm not sure why it references "/target/classes/..." as opposed to "/src/main/java/...".

This is the only FXML example I've found so I'm confused why I'm getting an error upon compiling, yet no errors are shown prior? Removing all reference to `TitledBorder` allows all my code to function/compile properly. Since its in the src package I use this code in FXML to connect w/ controller `fx:controller="loadController">`. CSS is added properly too.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the imports from your FXML file? As for "I'm not sure why it references "/target/classes/..." as opposed to "/src/main/java/...", surely that is because it's the location of your FXML file at runtime (rather than at compile time).

Comment: James, the problem was that I was using the default package and should've created a package inside my java package, and then referenced the TitledBorder class from there in the FXML. Thanks for showing interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
<?import TitledBorder?>
```

implies that you put the `TitledBorder.java` file to default package (i.e. no package declaration in source code of this file). However `FXMLLoader`'s source code checks the imports in FXML file and splits package path name and class name in `loadType(...)` below, to load the imported class later with `loadTypeForPackage()`:

```
private Class<?> loadType(String name, boolean cache) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    int i = name.indexOf('.');
    int n = name.length();
    while (i != -1
        && i < n
        && Character.isLowerCase(name.charAt(i + 1))) {
        i = name.indexOf('.', i + 1);
    }

    if (i == -1 || i == n) {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException();
    }

    String packageName = name.substring(0, i);
    String className = name.substring(i + 1);

    Class<?> type = loadTypeForPackage(packageName, className);

    if (cache) {
        classes.put(className, type);
    }

    return type;
}

// TODO Rename to loadType() when deprecated static version is removed
private Class<?> loadTypeForPackage(String packageName, String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return getClassLoader().loadClass(packageName + "." + className.replace('.', '$'));
}
```

The imported class name is "TitledBorder" so the variable `i` at the 1st line in `loadType` method will be evaluated as `name.indexOf('.') = -1`, and will throw `ClassNotFoundException` in the next lines of code.

Generally it is bad practice to use default packages. Put the TitledBorder.java into some package and import it as

```
<?import my.some.package.TitledBorder?>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks Uluk. Oddly enough I thought I tried this last night but apparently I created a package outside the `java` package as opposed to inside. I learned a few things from your post, appreciate it.