# GridPane with titled border

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to put a titled border around my `GridPane` and I'm having an issue with the border being on top title. Also I wonder which container will be the best for my problem. `GridPane` seems problematic here. Any easier way to do it?

Current result:

[image: screen capture]

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
               primaryStage.setTitle("GridPane");
                
                BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 210);
                
                GridPane grd =new GridPane();
                ColumnConstraints column1width = new ColumnConstraints(50);
                ColumnConstraints column2width = new ColumnConstraints(70);
                ColumnConstraints column3width = new ColumnConstraints(70);
                RowConstraints row1Height = new RowConstraints(30);
                grd.getColumnConstraints().addAll(column1width, column2width, column3width);
                grd.getRowConstraints().add(row1Height);

                Label source = new Label("Source");
                Label report = new Label("Report");
                TextField text1 = new TextField();
                TextField text2 = new TextField("report.txt");
                Button browse1 = new Button("Browse...");
                Button browse2 = new Button("Browse...");
                grd.setVgap(10);
                grd.setHgap(10);
                grd.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
                
                text1.setPrefSize(80, 20);
                text2.setPrefSize(80, 20);
                browse1.setPrefSize(80, 20);
                browse2.setPrefSize(80, 20);
                
                Label textIO = new Label("Text IO zone");
                textIO.getStyleClass().add("title");
                textIO.setPadding(new Insets(-40, -20, 0, 0));
                
                textIO.setPrefWidth(120);      
                grd.add(textIO, 0, 0);
                grd.add(source, 0, 0);
                grd.add(text1, 1, 0);
                grd.add(browse1, 2, 0);
                grd.add(report, 0, 1);
                grd.add(text2, 1, 1);
                grd.add(browse2, 2, 1);

                grd.getStyleClass().add("border");
                
                grd.prefHeightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty());
                
                root.getStyleClass().add("color");
                root.setLeft(grd);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.setMinHeight(250);
                primaryStage.setMinWidth(410);
                primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And css styles.

```
/* JavaFX CSS - Leave this comment until you have at least create one rule which uses -fx-Property */

    .title {
       -fx-background-color: aliceblue;
       -fx-translate-y: -5;
       -fx-content-display: bottom; 
    }
    .border {
       -fx-border-insets: 5;
       -fx-border-color: black;
    }
    .color{
        -fx-background-color: aliceblue;
    }
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you want it to look like, so it's hard to tell you where to start.

Comment: Maybe `TitledPane`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31909942/230513)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860960/groupbox-titledborder-in-javafx-2

Comment: In `JavaFx` `TitlePane` is the real equal, but you have to create your own if you want it to look exactly like a `C#` `GroupBox`.

Comment: The link I posted shows examples of both.

Comment: You can probably use your `GridPane`, but the `Label's` background color and the `GridPane's` background color should be the same as their `Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

There was a question not too long ago about this, but I can't find it. The key is setting all the backgrounds to the same color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <StackPane layoutX="150.0" layoutY="115.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-background-color: white;">
         <children>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0">
               <children>
                  <HBox spacing="10.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Source" />
                        <TextField prefWidth="125.0" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Browse.." />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox spacing="10.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Report" />
                        <TextField maxWidth="125.0" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Browse.." />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
               <StackPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="20.0" />
               </StackPane.margin>
            </VBox>
         </children></StackPane>
      <Label layoutX="164.0" layoutY="105.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="Text IO Zone" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image]